# How can I see what http traffic to a localhost in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have setup proxyman to see http request/response from my app to a remote host in Xcode.
My question is how can I do that for localhost? I don't see anything in Proxyman when I change my app to talk to a local host.  And I don't see anything in the Xcode 's networking' tab either.

Thank you.

Comment: what about Charles Proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Proxyman's troubleshooting guide for this very problem: https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/.local-doesnt-appear-in-proxyman

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can see any localhost traffic on Proxyman since the traffic doesn't go through Proxyman Server at port 9090.

To fix it, you should map the localhost to any fake domain in /etc/hosts file

1. Open /etc/host file with any Text Editor (Vim or Sublime)
2. Add

> 127.0.0.1 my-website.dev

or

> 0.0.0.0 my-website.dev

**my-website.dev** is a fake domain, you can choose any domain you like

[image: Map domain]

3. Finally, you can access your localhost by using new fake domain.

- http://localhost:3000 -> http://my-website.dev:3000
- http://localhost:3000/v1/user -> http://my-website.dev:3000/v1/user

4. They will appear on Proxyman as usual

You can read a Doc at: https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/couldnt-see-any-request-from-localhost-server